# Why does parent view onHover block child view onTapGesture and onHover events?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simplified example of my keyboard shortcut recorder view. The idea is you click anywhere on or within the capsule and record your keyboard shortcut. Once recorded it will display your shortcut and a x to clear the shortcut. If you're recording the keyboard shortcut and move the mouse away from the keyboard shortcut recorder, I need a way to stop the recording from happening. The following code used to work in Xcode 14 I'm pretty sure (Xcode 13 for sure) but now it seems to not be working anymore.

If you click on record shortcut, onTap doesn't run, neither does onHover. How can I make this work?

`simultaneousGesture` does not work in all three configurations that I tried (Child has - parent doesn't, child doesn't - parent does, child has - parent has)

*Paste the following into playground:*

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var recordedShortcut = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                // prompt user to record shortcut, once recorded show it
                Text(recordedShortcut ? "⌘A" : "Record Shortcut")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture { // <- Never executes, why??
                        print("inside tapped")
                        // do action when record shortcut is tapped
                    }.onHover { _ in // <- Also never executes
                        print("hovering")
                    }
                // if user recorded shortcut, show the shortcut and a x btn to clear it
                if recordedShortcut {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.labelColor))
                        .onTapGesture { // <- Won't ever execute even if onHover is outside zstack
                            recordedShortcut = false
                        }
                }
            }
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 1.5)
                .frame(width: 120, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.tertiaryLabelColor))
                .onHover { isHovering in // <- Blocks all tapGestures or 
                                         //    onHovers for views below this 
                                         //    one. I need it to work here.
                    if !isHovering {
                        print("exited frame")
                        // do whatever when stop hovering over the view
                    }
                }
        }.onTapGesture { // <- works to record,
                        //     but still blocks insides so no way
                        //     to press the x to clear the shortcut
            // this works but only in this simplfied example
            // I need it to work inside the z stack due to more
            // complex logic in the full code snippet
            recordedShortcut = true
        }
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```